# Connecting to Salesforce from C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am trying to set up a programming environment to programmatically access Salesforce from C#.  I have done this in Java previously, but would like to try it from C#.

I have imported WSDL's into a Visual Studio 2013 C# project which gives me access to most classes I need, however, I cannot access the ConnectorConfig object because it is located in WSC.  So, I cannot establish a login connection.

Suggestions?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have given the name for your service reference as "ServiceReference1". Do the following.

[Code sample is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wMfE.png)

Comment: Gnani, That almost worked.  I got the error you described and corrected the ListViewRecordColumn[][] to ListViewRecordColumn[].

Comment: However, now I am getting a new error:  "UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https."  Do you know how to set TLS 1.1 in this approach?

Comment: Found answer to my own question:  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;  sets the security protocal.  Looks like it is working now!  Thanks Gnani!